# When do commits happen with SQLAlchemy Core?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to test this out, but haven't been able to come to a definitive answer. I'm using SQLAlchemy on top of MySQL and trying to prevent having threads that do a select, get a `SHARED_READ` lock on some table, and then hold on to it (preventing future DDL operations until it's released). This happens when queries aren't committed. I'm using SQLAlchemy Core, where as far as I could tell `.execute()` essentially works in `autocommit` mode, issuing a `COMMIT` after everything it runs unless explicitly told we're in a transaction. Nevertheless, in `show processlist`, I'm seeing sleeping threads that still have `SHARED_READ` locks on a table they once queried. What gives?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming from your post you're operating in "non-transactional" mode, either using an SQLAlchemy `Connection` without an ongoing transaction, or the shorthand `engine.execute()`. In this mode of operation SQLAlchemy will detect `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and DDL statements and issue a commit after automatically, but not for everything, like `SELECT` statements. See ["Understanding Autocommit"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit). For selects of mutating stored procedures and such that do require a commit, use

```
conn.execute(text('SELECT ...').execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

You should also consider closing connections when the thread is done with them for the time being. Closing will call `rollback()` on the underlying DBAPI connection, which per PEP-0249 is (probably) always in transactional state. This will remove the transactional state and/or locks, and returns the connection to the connection pool. This way you shouldn't need to worry about selects not autocommitting.